# How to show custom 404 per controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to show different error pages based on the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Rails < 3.0.

Yes, it is possible. I use this method in my application controller to render 404 message:

```
def render_optional_error_file(status_code)
  status = interpret_status(status_code)[0,3]
  if status == "404"
    render :template => "/errors/404.html.erb", :status => status
  else
    render :template => "/errors/error.html.erb", :status => status
  end
end
```

So, the only thing you need to do is to write this method for each controller, or you can change `render` line to something like this:

```
render :template => error_page, :status => status
```

and add method:

```
def error_page
  "/errors/404.html.erb"
end
```

Then you only need to write `error_page` method in each controller, where you want to change default error page.

EDIT:
Ups, I've just noticed that this method is deprecated in Rails 3. So there should be another way of doing it.

For Rails >=3.0:

[Here](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/36-rails-3-0-rescue-from-routing-error-solution) is one example solution for this. Just add:

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_404
```

and add `render_404` method:

```
def render_404
  render :file => "errors/404.html.erb", :status => 404
end
```

Or if you want to add `404.html.erb` view for each controller without modifing controllers code, you can write it like this:

```
def render_404
  render "404.html.erb", :status => 404
end
```

I think it should look for this error file inside current controller's view directory. I didn't check it, but I think it should work. But remember to include `404.html.erb` file in each controller's view directory. Otherwise there could be an error.

Comment: Thanks. So I should duplicate it in every controller. I found a method that works in Rails 3: http://blog.igodigital.com/blog/notes-on-cyber-weekend-targeted-email-campaigns/custom-error-handling-in-rails-303